# Displaying a dropdown menu on hover and replacing CSS classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Two elements that needs to be manipulated with JS:

```
<li class="navTab myFirstTab Popup PopupControl PopupOpen PopupContainerControl">
```

For the above element:
I want OnMouseHover to replace the class value:
PopupClose with PopupOpen

```
<div class="Menu JsOnly tabMenu myFirstTabLinks" id="XenForoUniq0" style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 96px; left: 960.5px;">
```

At the same time, the above element style attribute to change its value from:
 display: none; to display: block;

Sample of HTML structure:

```
<ul class="publicTabs navLeft">
    <li class="navTab forums selected">
     <a href="#" class="navLink">Home</a>
     <a href="#" class="SplitCtrl" rel="Menu"></a>
    </li>                                   

    <li class="navTab myFirstTab Popup PopupControl PopupClosed     PopupContainerControl">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">On hover I should have a DropDown</a>
      <a href="#" class="SplitCtrl" rel="Menu"></a>
    </li>

     <li class="navTab mySecondTab Popup PopupControl PopupClosed PopupContainerControl uix_rightMost">
        <a href="#"  class="navLink">On hover I should have a DropDown​2</a>
        <a href="#" class="SplitCtrl"      rel="Menu"></a>
     </li>
                            <!-- members -->
                            <!-- extra tabs: end -->
                            <!-- responsive popup -->
                            <li class="navTab navigationHiddenTabs navTab--j    justIcon Popup PopupControl PopupClosed PopupContainerControl" style="display: none;">
                                <a rel="Menu" class="navLink NoPopupGadget uix_dropdownDesktopMenu"><i class="uix_icon uix_icon-navOverflow"></i><span class="uix_hide menuIcon">ham</span></a>
                            </li>

</ul>


 <!-- START DropDown-->
 <div class="Menu JsOnly tabMenu myFirstTabLinks" id="XenForoUniq0"   style="display: none; visibility: visible; top: 96px; left: 960.5px;">
     <div class="primaryContent menuHeader">
         <h3>My First drop down menu title</h3>
     </div>     

<ul class="secondaryContent blockLinksList">
       <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="Menu JsOnly tabMenu mySecondTabLinks" id="XenForoUniq1"     style="display: none; visibility: visible; top: 76px; left: 879.5px;">
     <div class="primaryContent menuHeader">
           <h3>My Second drop down menu title</h3>
     </div>

 <ul class="secondaryContent blockLinksList">
      <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
 </ul>                                      
</div>

<!-- FINISH DropDown -->
```

Comment: What is the element on which you want the hover event???

Comment: `myFirstTab` class would carry the dropdown of `myFirstTabLinks` and `mySecondTab` class would have the dropdown of `mySecondTabLink`,

Comment: Check the edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data-target attributes to your tablinks div.. similar to below

```
<li class="navTab myFirstTab Popup PopupControl PopupClosed  PopupContainerControl" data-target="myFirstTabLinks">
<li class="navTab mySecondTab Popup PopupControl PopupClosed  PopupContainerControl" data-target="mySecondTabLinks">
```

Now

```
$('.navTab.Popup').on('mouseenter', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('PopupClosed').addClass('PopupOpen');
   var cls = $(this).data('target'); // fetch which class to target.
   $('.Menu.' + cls).css('display','block'); // will make display block
}). on('mouseleave', function() {
   $(this).addClass('PopupClosed').removeClass('PopupOpen');
   var cls = $(this).data('target'); // fetch which class to target.
   $('.Menu.' + cls).css('display','none'); // will make display none
});
```

Comment: Yes... that is how you should do it.

Comment: The jquery code isn't taking effect on navlink hover, nothing happens,  it's supposed to be applied for: ` <li class="navTab myFirstTab Popup PopupControl PopupClosed     PopupContainerControl">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">On hover I should have a DropDown</a>
      <a href="#" class="SplitCtrl" rel="Menu"></a>
    </li> `

Comment: Sorry.. i made the reverse behaviour.. plz wait.. i am editing my code

Comment: Thanks, the PopupClosed is now being replaced with PopupOpen on mousehover, although display:block; isn't taking effect. I added the data targets, also on mousehover both navigation links get their class PopupClosed replaced with PopupOpen, and I only want the one that is active

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134243/discussion-between-yogesh-kumar-gupta-and-t0r).